# Webcam not detected on macbook pro UBUNTU 16.04?

Tags: webcam, macbook-pro

My webcam isn't detected on Ubuntu 16.04. Below is the output of `cheese`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you running in a VM?

Comment: NO! I Have done Dual boot @AndroidDev